# Regex to handle letters, numbers and % symbol

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to write a regex to identify a token using a string with the following pattern:

`'eyAidXNlcl9pZCI6NywidG9rZW5fY3JlYXRpb25fdGltZSI6MTQyMDQ4NTUyMS4zNyB9%0A'`

or

`'eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo3LCJ0b2tlbl9jcmVhdGlvbl90aW1lIjoxNDIwNDk0MTcxLjc5fQ%3D%3D'`

My django url is structured using the following pattern:

`url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/email/(?P<token>[a-f0-9]{100})/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', objects.ObjectDetail.as_view(), name="create-using-token"),`

I can't figure out what the regex to parse the token `(?P<token>[a-f0-9]{100})` should be as I'm unsure how to handle the `%` symbol. I'm generating these tokens elsewhere using `urllib` (Specifically, `urllib.quote(string.encode("base64"))`)

My code block for testing this in the shell is as follows:

```
import re
token = 'eyAidXNlcl9pZCI6NywidG9rZW5fY3JlYXRpb25fdGltZSI6MTQyMDQ4NTUyMS4zNyB9%0A'
pattern = '\w+\W+'
re.findall(pattern, token)
```

I've tried using `[a-f0-9]{100}`, `'\w+\W+'` and `[\w|\W]` . These get very close, but I'm not sure how to handle this `%` symbol as they either split, or ignore what is after the `%`.

I'm generating the token using the following approach:

```
def generate_token():
   now = time.time()
   raw_string = '{{"random_number":{random_number},"token_creation_time":{now}}}'.format(
    random_number=random_number,
    now=now).strip()
   token = raw_string.encode("base64")
   return urllib.quote(token)
```

Per @alecxe's suggestion I have experimented with `.rstrip('\n')` to remove the `\n` that the encoding adds in, but I still need to be able to identify tokens that contain the `%` symbol

Answer (score 2):

If you unquote `%0A`, you'll see that it is a new line character:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('%0A')
'\n'
```

You probably accidentally left it in the token string. I think you don't want tokens to contain it and therefore you don't need to try matching the token with a new-line at the end.

---

Looking at the `generate_token()` function. It is a feature of [`base64` encoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.encode) to add a trailing new-line at the end of the encoded string. Strip it:

```
 token = raw_string.encode("base64").rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: That's strange. I'm programmatically generating them, and constructing my string using `"".format()` I'm not adding a new-line at the end.

Comment: @celenius what if you call [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on the string before sending the token?

Comment: Even with `strip()` it's still ending with `%0A`

Comment: @celenius could you show the code that is meant for generating and sending the token (as much as possible, relevant part)? Thanks.

Comment: I just added it in - thanks for your suggestions so far!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd prefer not to strip it out as I unencode it from base 64 too. Is there a strong reason why I should not just revise the regex to handle it?

Comment: @celenius well, I'm not sure about it, but it doesn't sound quite right to handle newline characters in django urls - haven't seen it before..sorry, thanks.